# link-to doesn't fire transitions, and doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got a link-to, built by current position, that for some reason doesn't do anything.
I've turned on logging Transitions, and all I get is:

`Attempting transition to customer.goodie-pack`, which is the route name.

I've defined a transition in app/transitions.js, but nothing seems to happen, when I click the link. I've confirmed, that the  actually has the correct href-tag. I just cannot figure out, why the click doesn't do anything. It is almost as if, something returns false, but doesn't log it (Which I believe could be some hook returning false or alike, but I'm unaware of anything firing.. The beforeModel/Model/afterModel-hooks, are AFAIK logged, when happening?)

I'm using the almost exact same script between two other routes, that works just fine, and logs as follows:

```
Attempting transition to customer.index
Preparing to transition from 'customer.goodie-pack' to 'customer.index'
Transition #1: customer.index: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #1: customer.index: calling deserialize hook
Transition #1: customer.index: calling afterModel hook
Transition #1: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition.
Transitioned into 'customer.index'
Transition #1: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

Thus calling the hooks in the "transition-to"-route. I'm not even seeing the "preparing"-call?

I'm not enough into ember, to know when which log is called in the source-code.

More info from Ember-Inspector:

- Ember    2.9.0
- Ember Data   2.9.0
- jQuery   3.1.1

Comment: Did you forgot {{outlet}} in corresponding template.hbs ?. I am not aware of defining transitions in `app/transitions.js,` ?. Could you please explain, what is this supposed to with transition ?.

Comment: That could be a module, with that function, that's just "prettifying" them, like how they transition in the frontend.

Which template, are you thinking about here?

Comment: Without having more information about your router and templates this isn't possible to debug remotely. As @kumkanillam says, the transition may have occurred correctly but you're missing an outlet (so there's no place to render the template into) or some other reason.

app/transition.js is a file used by the animation library liquid-fire, and is not related to transitioning between routes.

Comment: Can you use a service like https://ember-twiddle.com/ to re-create the issue you're seeing?

Comment: The template is rendered, and shown correctly. But when I click the link, it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: It's a project I've been put into recently, and it's getting quite large, and I don't think I'll be able to reproduce it in a twiddle.

Comment: Not the _entire_ project, just the specific area you are having trouble with. Without being able to isolate this into a reproducible example, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133460/discussion-between-trek-glowacki-and-frederik-spang).